# How do I compare two columns taken from different excel files in python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to extract two columns, each column taken from two different excel files, the contents of the columns are in a different order and have few different items in them as well, so I am trying to check if the contents of one column are present in the other and if it is present, I want to print the corresponding value from an another column, this is what I have come up with so far

```
import pandas as pd
A = pd.read_excel('testcase_database.xlsx') #The excel file from which the data is to be taken
B = pd.read_excel('S32K3XX_SecureBAF_Sprint3_Test_Report.xlsx', sheet_name='Test_Report') #The excel file to which the data is to be updated
tcname = A['Unnamed: 2'] #Test case nams in A
fcname = B['Unnamed: 5'] #Test case names in B
pf = B['Unnamed: 15'] #Results in B
pi = A['Unnamed: 5'] #Results in A

temp = ""
temp1 = ""
#To compare the test case names in A and B and then printing that test case result in B
for i in tcname:
    temp = tcname[i]
    for j in fcname:
        temp1 = fcname[j]
        if temp==temp1:
            print(pf[j])
        else:
            continue
```

I am getting a key error, what is it I am doing wrong

Comment: can you provide a sample of the two input dataframes?

Comment: Do you mean the excel files I am using?

Comment: I should suggest you to use unordered maps it will make your code faster.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the current and expected output.

Comment: @AMC for simple code like this, is not just reading the code and making a suggestion good enough? If it helps someone out, then isn't it useful?

Comment: @TimJim They mention a specific error, I'd prefer to get a MCVE than take a guess at where the error might be.

Comment: @AMC I see, fair enough! Perhaps I thought the error was obvious as I had just dealt with something similar not long ago, but I guess that it could appear obscure to someone who hasn't used the Pandas module recently.

Comment: @TimJim I agree that it doesn't seem too complicated, but that may be different for the OP.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's likely throwing a `KeyError` on the line `temp = tcname[i]` because `for i in tcname:` loops through the values of your column `tcname`. i.e. `i` = `some_row_value` - you can't then use that as an index key in `tcname[i]`.

I don't have your inputs but this might achieve the same thing:

```py
import pandas as pd
A = pd.read_excel('testcase_database.xlsx') #The excel file from which the data is to be taken
B = pd.read_excel('S32K3XX_SecureBAF_Sprint3_Test_Report.xlsx', sheet_name='Test_Report') #The excel file to which the data is to be updated
tcname = A['Unnamed: 2'] #Test case nams in A
fcname = B['Unnamed: 5'] #Test case names in B
pf = B['Unnamed: 15'] #Results in B
pi = A['Unnamed: 5'] #Results in A

for temp in tcname:
    for j, temp1 in enumerate(fcname):
        if temp == temp1:
            print(pf[j])
        else:
            continue
```

Comment: Now what i wanted to do is, instead of printing, I was trying to do this pf[j] = pi[i], but it throws me a SettingWithCopyWarning: A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame, what is going wrong over here?

Comment: @RevanthKumarPerla It could be because `pf` is actually a copy of your column `pf = B['Unnamed: 15']` - so setting a value in it won't change the original data in the column `B['Unnamed: 15']`. Just a guess, but you can try using `iat` or `iloc`: `B['Unnamed: 15'].iat[j] = pi[i]`. See if you can experiment with that (I may have got the indexing wrong) the docs for `iat`: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html#pandas.DataFrame.iat

Comment: Yes this is working now, but how do i update that whole column in the given excel sheet, right now it is only updated in the dataframe and not in the excel file

Comment: @RevanthKumarPerla Editing the dataframe created using `pd.read_excel` won't affect the original source - you can think of it as a data import into python. If you want to save the edited dataframe back out again to a new excel file, you can check out the `to_excel` method https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html - something like `A.to_excel('output_filename')`

Comment: Is there any way just to update a specified column, converting the data frame to an excel file is taking a lot of time to complete as there are around 500 rows of data with around 20 columns?

Comment: Is there any other data processing going on that is taking time? With the larger datasets I work with, I never noticed `to_excel` taking a noticeable among of time! With regards to updating the column directly, I've seen some posts using openpyxl or xlrd but I've not tried them before and they seem to come with other considerations!